# Red border around TextBox when validation fails

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2.

Html.DropDownListFor and Html.TextAreaFor automatically get red borders when the validation fails.

How to make the four borders of a TextBox (using Html.TextBoxFor) red when it fails validation?

For example, I have a TextBox that is required and when the user submits the form without specifying a value in the textbox, I want the textbox to have red borders.

Comment: Refer
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9849/change-background-color-of-a-control-when-validation-fails-i.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When validation fails for a model property - it'll add a class to the input in the html. Have a look at the rendered html when the validation fails (using view source or firebug) and check out the class for your input*. Then edit your css to include a style for the failed validation.

E.g. In my project I have:

```
input.input-validation-error,
textarea.input-validation-error,
select.input-validation-error
{
    background: #FEF1EC;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
```

HTHs,
Charles

* I'm pretty sure ASP.NET MVC add the class `input-validation-error` by default.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I found out that the following css (in Site.css):

input[type="text"] 
{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

was overriding this css:

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

Therefore, the borders of the TextBoxes never turned red when the validation failed. By changing the css to the following

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

the borders are red when the validation fails.

Comment: Many thanks its works for me also with this approach ....`INPUT[type='radio'],
.input-validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
}`

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is the CSS below:

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```